# How to click the button on the following website?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to the world of python and I am trying to select a couple of options on the following website and then click the search button to update results. However, I cannot get the button to respond.

I tried using search button.click() and .submit() and I have tried to implicitly wait. I have also used the code below to wait until the button is clickable. When executing the code, it highlights the button but doesn't seem to release the click; almost like a half click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://leasing.com/personal/car-leasing/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('selUpfront')
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("3")
element = driver.find_element_by_id('selMileage')
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("8000")
searchbutton = WebDriverWait(driver,     20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "search-button")))
searchbutton.click()
```

I would expect the search results to be updated with the conditions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were close. To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#search-button>i.fa.fa-search#search-button-icon"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='search-button']/i[@class='fa fa-search' and @id='search-button-icon']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: car]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 elements with the search-button you need to use the xpath to locate specific

```
searchbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='search-button']")))
searchbutton.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the same issue happens in that it does not do anything on click - you can see the button highlight in blue, then return to orange as if it had been clicked, but it does not update the page with the filters selected.